# Compiling/Linking: Skipping incompatible versions of library

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors

I am compiling a project which works fine until linking.
The linker stops on 2 libraries:
`libcrypto_t` and `libssl_t`. Both are "incompatible"according to `/usr/bin/ld`.
How can I find out what causes the problem? gcc version different from the gcc version used to compile the libraires? Do I need to recompile the openssl with the currently installed gcc version?

Comment: More likely you're compiling 64bit binary, while these libraries are 32bit, or vice versa. Or you using different toolchain (e.g. crosscompiling)

Comment: No my Target is definetly a 32bit binary.

Comment: What this '_t' supposed to mean? Anyway, just use `readelf -h /usr/lib/libssl_t*.so` and compare it to e.g. hello-world program compiled with the same flags you using (but without these libs). If it wouldn't give you an answer, add results to the question.

Comment: I got it working. I provided a LIBRARY_PATH to libraries for a different architecture. Added /usr/local/lib and made a symbolic link from libcrypto_t.s to libcrypto.a